# Can F-Test be used for arbitrary nested non-linear model selection

Tags: model-selection, nonlinear, f-test

Suppose I have data consisting of pairs $(x_i,y_i)$. To this I want to fit a function $\hat{y}_i=f(x_i;a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, where $a_j$ are parameters. The functions nest in the sense that setting the $n^{\text{th}}$ parameter to zero is equivalent to dropping it from the model.

The function $f$ is given by theory, is highly non-linear, and has no closed form solution so I use the following procedure:

1. Calculate $\text{SSE}(a_1)=\sum_i[f(x_i;a_1)-y_i]^2$ for many values of $a_1$ and take that which minimises the sum of squared errors to be the best fit. Denote the associated $\min\text{SSE}$ with $\epsilon^*(1)$.
2. Calculate $\text{SSE}(a_1,a_2)=\sum_i[f(x_i;a_1,a_2)-y_i]^2$ for many values of $(a_1,a_2)$ and take that which minimises the sum of squared errors to be the best fit. Denote the associated $\min\text{SSE}$ with $\epsilon^*(2)$.
3. Repeat for $n=3,\ldots,N$.

Now I would like to formally test whether the model with $N$ parameters yields a statistically significant improvement in fit over that with $N-m$ parameters. Can I legitimately do this by calculating an F-statistic:
$$\frac{\frac{\epsilon^*(N-m)-\epsilon^*(N)}{\epsilon^*(N)}}{\frac{m}{N-m}}\sim F(m,N-m)?$$

Or is there some other approach that should be used for model selection under these circumstances?